# Integrate LDAP server with vanilla forum

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, single-sign-on, vanilla-forums

I'm trying to integrate vanilla forum with my company LDAP server. It's not successful. I have no idea what's wrong :(

Here's how I do this:

The flow:

[image]

The plugin jsconnect is installed and config as follow:

- ClientID: generated
- Secret: generated
- Authentication URL:LoginController.php

Source of `LoginController.php`

```
<?php
include 'ChromePhp.php';
require_once 'functions.jsconnect.php';

// using ldap bind

$user_ = $_POST['user'];
$pass_ = $_POST['pass'];


// $ldaprdn  = 'uid=riemann,dc=example,dc=com';     // ldap rdn or dn
// $ldappass = 'password';  // associated password
$ldaprdn  = 'uid=';
$ldaprdn.=$user_.',dc=example,dc=com';
$ldappass=$pass_;
ChromePhp::log($ldaprdn);
// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap.forumsys.com")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

ChromePhp::log("LDAP bind start...");
$validatedUser= FALSE;
if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        // echo "LDAP bind successful...";
        ChromePhp::log("LDAP bind successful...");
        $validatedUser =TRUE;
    } else {
        // echo "LDAP bind failed...";
        ChromePhp::log("LDAP bind failed...");
    }

}

$attributes = array('mail','cn');
$accountname = $user_; 
$filter_person = "uid={$accountname}";
$search = ldap_search($ldapconn,"DC=example,DC=com",$filter_person , $attributes);
$data = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $search);
ChromePhp::log($data);
$fullname= $data[0]['cn'];
$mail= $data[0]['mail'];
ChromePhp::log($fullname);
ChromePhp::log($mail);
#intergrate
$clientID = "string";
$secret = "stringSecret";

$userArray = array();
if ($validatedUser) {
   // CHANGE THESE FOUR LINES.
   ChromePhp::log("start fill user...");
   $userArray['uniqueid'] = $user_;
   $userArray['name'] = $fullname['0'];
   $userArray['email'] = $mail['0'];
   $userArray['photourl'] = ''; 

}
// 4. Generate the jsConnect string.
// This should be true unless you are testing. 
// You can also use a hash name like md5, sha1 etc which must be the name as the connection settings in Vanilla.
ChromePhp::log($userArray);
$secure = false; 
WriteJsConnect($userArray, $_GET, $clientID, $secret, $secure);
//header("Location: ../../../v/"); /* Redirect browser */  //somehow add this make the file stop working :p 
//exit();
?>
```

The problem is

- The LoginController output is {"name":"","photourl":""} Seems not
  right.
- When php jump past `WriteJsConnect($user, $_GET, $clientID,
  $secret, $secure);` nothing happen, no new user created, the role is
  still guest.

Comment: @VeeK did you manage it to work?

Comment: Months later it is barely working. I don't know nothing about LDAP but here's the basic concept. When user clicks on Login/register page, you send them to a normal login page of your website (Login Url). Don't do anything special, just log him in, plain as vanilla (lol) then send them back to the forums. When the user comes back to forums, vanilla will automatically ping your "Authenticatio Url". On this page, you merely see if the user is logged in via your usual methods, if he is, you add the variables to that `$userArray` otherwise you pass an empty array to `WriteJsConnect`.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean barely working? Is the login have some parameters to trigger "Authentication Url"?

Comment: The authentication url doesnot send signature parameters to get a full response so the user sees his name and avatar and he has to click on it again to complete signin. So it requires two clicks. I have an open question about it [here](https://open.vanillaforums.com/discussion/33424/jsconnect-doesnt-send-the-timestamp). The login url does nothing for authentication url like I said. On login page, don't do anything other that loggin user in

Comment: It's sad that support on that forum is almost dead :( Vanilla is a very potential forum software :(

Comment: What's your progress now? I'd love to help out to the best of my ability.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness, I managed to generate the JSONP string from LoginController, but somehow after refresh the forum page, it's only appear the SSO description string not a clickable sign in :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143388/discussion-between-veek-and-tiana987642).

Comment: SO don't have PM :( Just want to say thank you, @VeeK . You're very kind and helpful. Pity that my company decided to use another platform. Though free vanilla show so much potential, but the support for devs is nearly non existence :(

Comment: Thank you Tiana, and good luck to you.